# 3D Touch for iOS 9 Web App on Home Screen?

Tags: ios, web-applications, ios9, iphone-web-app

iOS 9 continues the trend to support web apps via their limited tag support as defined here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

And additionally it is possible to implement functionality such as event listeners for touchstart / touchmove / touchend events.
Example code here: https://github.com/freinbichler/3d-touch/blob/master/3dtouch.js

But, is it possible to expose and define peek and pop functionality or other Quick Actions (App Shortcuts) options for a web app icon on the home screen?